# What's wrong with relative imports in Python?

Tags: coding-style, python

I recently upgraded versions of [pylint](http://www.logilab.org/card/pylint_manual), a popular Python style-checker.

It has gone ballistic throughout my code, pointing out places where I import modules in the same package, without specifying the full package path.

The new error message is W0403.

> W0403:    Relative import %r, should be %r
>
> Used when an import relative to the package directory is detected.

---

#### Example

For example, if my packages are structured like this:

```
/cake
  /__init__.py
  /icing.py
  /sponge.py
/drink
```

and in the sponge package I write:

```
import icing
```

instead of

```
import cake.icing
```

I will get this error.

---

While I understand that not all Pylint messages are of equal importance, and I am not afraid to dismiss them, I don't understand why such a practice is considered a poor idea.

I was hoping someone could explain the pitfalls, so I could improve my coding style rather than (as I currently plan to do) turning off this apparently spurious warning.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

The problem of `import icing` is that you don't know whether it's an absolute import or a relative import. `icing` could be a module in python's path, or a package in the current module. This is quite annoying when a local package has the same name  as a python standard library package.

You can do `from __future__ import absolute_import` which turns off implicit relative imports altogether. It is described, including with this justification about ambiguity, in [PEP 328](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-328). I believe Python 3 has implicit relative imports turned off completely.

You still can do relative imports, but you have to do them explicitly, like this:

```
from . import icing
```

Comment: +1 especially for the compromise solution, which is probably the way I should go.

Comment: Note you can also do `import .icing` instead of `from . import icing`

Comment: @Jack actually I don't think you can. From [this part of PEP328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#guido-s-decision):

Relative imports must always use `from <> import` ; `import <>` is always absolute. Of course, absolute imports can use `from <> import` by omitting the leading dots. The reason `import .foo` is prohibited is because after

`import XXX.YYY.ZZZ`
then

`XXX.YYY.ZZZ`
is usable in an expression. But

`.moduleY`
is not usable in an expression.

Answer (score 65):

There are a few good reasons:

1. Relative imports break easily, when you move a module around.

   Imagine you have a `foo.bar`, a `foo.baz` and a `baz` module in your package. `foo.bar` imports `foo.baz`, but using a relative import.

   Now, if you were to move `foo.bar` to `bar`, your module suddenly is importing a different `baz`!
2. Relative imports are ambiguous. Even without moving around the `bar` module in the above example, a new developer coming to your project could be forgiven for not realizing that `baz` is really `foo.baz` instead of the root-level `baz` package.

   Absolute imports make it explicit what module is being used. And as `import this` preaches, explicit is better than implicit.
3. Python 3 has disabled implicit relative imports altogether; imports are now always interpreted as absolute, meaning that in the above example `import baz` will always import the top-level module. You will have to use the explicit import syntax instead (`from . import baz`).

   Porting the example from Python 2 to 3 would thus lead to unexpected problems, using absolute imports now will make your code future-proof.

Comment: +1 for #2 and #3. But #1 must be offset against what happens when the whole directory is moved (e.g. pushed down a level).

Comment: foo, bar and baz are the equivalents of variable names *d*, *b*, *p* and *q*, confusing and requiring additional mental load to tell them appart. Therefore downvote.

Comment: @problemofficer: those variable names are going to cause you problems everywhere in your career, I'm afraid. They are pretty much standard.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I agree but "Everyone else does it, therefore it is OK" is not a valid counter-argument.

Comment: @problemofficer: every professional software developer also uses terms like queues and frontend and backend. Jargon is part of the job, of the way we communicate. When posting answers on a Software Engineering Q&A, I use standard terminology. I'm sorry that you feel that *foo*, *bar* and *baz* are not part of the normal vocabulary, but all I can tell you is that I'm not going to follow you trying to get rid of them.